# How do I install a quill stem extender?

Tags: handlebars, stem, adapter

I don’t understand how to install a quill stem extender. Photo included. I have my stem, the long screw and the wedge. The stem extender on the right has a stem, a long screw, and a wedge. The screws hold the wedges on. I’m confused. I put the stem extender in. But do I leave the screw? Then how does my stem go into that? And no screw is long enough to reach through it all. I really don’t understand. Do all wedges and screws get used?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Sorry - you have the wrong part, or need a second part to make it all work.

The item on the right is a quill stem to threadless adapter, and if you used it to replace your current stem it would effectively be lower, and also require you to buy a stem

I'm not aware of a quill-stem extender, and if one was made it could end up quite wobbly, and too close to the chest.

Your other option is to fit new handlebars with more "rise" to them, in that they swoop-upward more.

Threadless stem examples - some have more "up" to them which will give you some more rise.  These are general indicative images, not specific recommendations.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://velo-orange.com/products/vo-happy-stem-31-8mm) is a better example?  Also from VO, with a 45deg rise.

Comment: @DavidW probably isn't it says "This stem will not work with the threadless stem adapter" i think it needs more space to clamp onto than the adapters provide

Comment: @GageMartin I meant the pictured extender (right side of OP's photo) cannot work with a quill stem (left)  it will need a threadless stem.

Comment: @Criggie I am not sure what purpose the pictures of the threadless stems in the answer are serving unless they are related to using them with the adapter. I was mentioning that one of the pictured threadless stems is specifically not compatible with the adapter (as stated on the Velo Orange site)

Comment: @GageMartin correct  - this shows OP what they could buy to make use of their quill-threadless adapter.  Second stem shows that some have more "rise" and can give some of the height required in OP's initial request.    I didn't want to just say "you got the wrong part" without giving some options.

Comment: So we don’t think there is just a part I can buy and use my current handlebars? 

I basically am looking for the cheapest easiest way to raise my handlebars for a more upright position. 

This guys seemed to do it. But I don’t understand how to buy a “quill extender” that isn’t actually an adaptor. 
https://youtu.be/30yMOoJBxaA

Comment: @sarah in that video, at 2 minutes there's a shot of the quill stem rammed into the top of the extender.  Presumably that extender has a bolt/wedge down inside the bike AND enough space for a second quill wedge in the top.  Your pictured quill-threadless adapter has the bolt poking out the top, so its a bit different to what they've used.

Comment: @Criggie maybe I am not being clear. What I am saying is that the second stem with more "rise" won't work with a quill-threadless adapter. copied from the description on VO's site "This stem will not work with the threadless stem adapter and is not to be used with carbon steerer tubes."

Comment: @Criggie I believe the part in the video is this (or something performing the same function) https://www.ebay.com/itm/CROMO-Quill-Bicycle-Stem-EXTENDER-21-1mm-22-2mm-25-4mm-Bikes-Cycling-/153214219733

Comment: @GageMartin I hear you.  That specific stem has restrictions.  However the image shows there exist stems that go upward.  That was the point of that photo.   The separate problem is as initially described, the quill-threadless adapter in OP's photo is functionally different to your ebay link.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the exact same predicament, same items, same confusion.

There is a very easy solution. You need a longer quill.

You're raising it up so the Quill/Wedge that attaches to bike stem would have to be longer as well.

Measure your quill. I think all standard ones are 6.5”/165.1mm so the riser I got was 2" higher (8.5”/215.9mm). Couldn't find 215.9mm but 230mm okay (9"). I just bought one at https://www.universalcycles.com

Good luck if you still need it and happy riding!

Comment: Could you add a picture to improve your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quill stem extender looks like this:
[image]

A quill stem adaptor looks like this:
[image]

If you have a quill stem extender here's how it should be installed.

[image]

I always put wheel bearing grease on the wedge - all sides - and bolt where it threads into the wedge. This prevents rust and assures that both the extender and the stem can be removed in the future.

1. The quill extender is inserted all the way into the fork and the extender bolt tightened.
2. The stem is inserted into the quill extender and the stem bolt tightened.

I recommend a longer stem rather than using an extender